# Changing content based on which button was clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two `UIViewControllers` which are linked together.

The first `UIViewController` has 4 `UIButtons`, all of which take me to the second `UIViewController`.

But, the content should change depending on which button I have clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give each button a unique tag and use the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in which you can check the tag of the button clicked, and then change your content accordingly.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *buttonSender = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSLog(@"Tag of the button tag selected = %d", buttonSender.tag);

   switch (buttonSender.tag) {
        case 1:
            // Content if button 1 was clicked.
            break;
        case 2:
            // Content if button 2 was clicked.
            break;
        case 3:
            // Content if button 3 was clicked.
            break; 
        case 4:
            // Content if button 4 was clicked.
            break;   
        default:
            break; 
   }
}
```